# How to make my JS button accept user input? I want to submit multiple values in one prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to create a button in JS once clicked, asks the user to enter the AUTHOR, and TITLE of the book. I want to take that input and transfer it somewhere else. However, I'm having a hard time coding this button.

I've written thus far is this:

```
  $('span.addall').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var title, author;
      title = prompt("Please enter title");
      author = prompt("Please enter author")
    });
```

However, the issue with the above code is that 2 separate windows pop up back to back asking the user to enter information. Is it possible I can write the JS code so that it asks for both the title and author on one window, and has 2 different input boxes? I also want to make sure that it won't allow the user to SUBMIT the data without having both the fields completed. Some sort of alert. This is kinda how I would like the button to work once clicked, I used paint to edit the picture:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

my books.jsp page which needs the fix:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 5 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Database Project</title>   

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <spring:url value="/webjars/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" var="bootstrap"/>
  <spring:url value="/webjars/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" var="jquery"/>
  <spring:url value="/webjars/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" var="bootstrapJS"/>
  <spring:url value="/webjars/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" var="bootstrapTable"/>
  <spring:url value="/webjars/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js" var="bootstrapTableJS"/>  
  <spring:url value="/resources/css/entertainment.css" var="entertainmentCss"/>
  <spring:url value="/resources/js/script.js" var="tableJS"/>

  <link href="${bootstrap}" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="${bootstrapTable}" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="${entertainmentCss}" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body> 
  <div class="site-wrapper">
    <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
      <div class="cover-container">
        <div class="masthead clearfix">
          <div class="inner">
            <h3 class="masthead-brand">Entertainment App</h3>
              <nav>
                <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>                  
                </ul>
              </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="inner cover">
          <div class="entertainmentDisplay"> 
            <h1>Books</h1>                      
            <table class="zebra-style" id="dtable">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkall" />
                  </th>
                  <th scope="col">Title</th>
                  <th scope="col">Author</th>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>              
                <c:forEach var="book" items="${books}">
                  <tr>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="selectedItems" 
                        value="<c:out value="${book.booksKey}"/>"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${book.title}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${book.author}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${book.booksKey}"/></td>
                  </tr>
                </c:forEach>
              <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <!--<th colspan="2"><a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default deleteall" title="dtable">Delete Selected Items</a></th>-->
                  <th colspan="2"><span href="javascript:;" id= "formsubmit" class="btn btn-default deleteall" title="dtable">Delete Selected Items</span></th>
                  <th colspan="2"><span href="javascript:;" id= "formsubmit" class="btn btn-default addall" title="dtable">Add Item(s)</span></th>

                </tr>
              </tfoot>
              </tbody>
            </table>           
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mastfoot">
          <div class="inner">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="${jquery}"></script>
  <script src="${bootstrapJS}"></script>
  <script src="${bootstrapTableJS}"></script>
  <script src="${tableJS}"></script>        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While you can't take more than 1 inputs with prompt separately, you have some other options. First, you need form and model. For the forms, have a look at MDN [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/How_to_structure_an_HTML_form) which shows structure and for the modal look at jquery [documentation](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form). For your example which takes title and author as parameter and pass it to variable Here is the working [fiddler](http://codepen.io/cmlonder/pen/BKPZJg)

Comment: @cmlonder wow this is really good, only problem is I need to implement in my books.jsp page which I've put in my updated post above. Think you could help out with that? I already have a delete function and a table coded which are working as expected, it's the 'add' button that's messed up.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using Bootstrap modals for this.
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

You can easily include a modal to show when clicking the button

See the example on "Varying modal content based on trigger button"